# Google Sheets QUERY function to return records with multiple filter criteria based on cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a dataset on Google Sheets similar to below.

| Name | Team | Account | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jennifer | East | Meta | 5/1/2023 |
| Steve | East | Alphabet | 4/1/2023 |
| Claire | West | Google | 4/23/2023 |
| Roger | West | Apple | 6/23/2023 |
| Bob | West | Walmart | 5/12/2023 |

I am trying to use the QUERY function to return columns Name, Account and Date sorted Ascending by date. On another sheet with filter criteria, I want to reference cell A1 where Team = "West" and date range is referenced to cell A2 and A3 with a beginning (A2) and ending (A3) date range.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the query statement using text string concatenation, like this:

```
=query( 
  Sheet1!A1:D, 
  "select A, C, D 
   where B = '" & A1 & "' 
   and date " & text(A2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " <= toDate(D) 
   and toDate(D) <= date " & text(A2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " 
   order by D asc", 
  1 
)
```

For easier debugging, you can put this in another cell, say `A4`, to see what the query statement looks like:

```
= "select A, C, D 
   where B = '" & A1 & "' 
   and date " & text(A2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " <= toDate(D) 
   and toDate(D) <= date " & text(A2, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " 
   order by D asc"
```

You can also use that query statement directly in the `query()` formula, like this:

```
=query(Sheet1!A1:D, A4, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks doubleunary! Is there a way to return records if Team = East OR West? For example if cell A1 is East, West.

Comment: Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.